# Bootstrap 3 fancyfile breaks when used in tab-pane

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Fancyfile jQuery plugin for Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 (http://plugins.upbootstrap.com/bootstrap-fancyfile/) to theme my file inputs to be more Bootstrap-like.

When use it on an input in a `tab-pane` which *isn't the visible tab-pane on load*, the input breaks; It gets narrow, the placeholder text disappears, and clicking on the right part of the input can trigger a form submit. What is the conflict and is there a way to fix this?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dbailey/bv2swf2t/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#main" data-toggle="tab">Description</a></li>
                <li><a href="#photos" data-toggle="tab">Photos</a></li>                                 
                <li><a href="#contributors" data-toggle="tab">Contributors</a></li>

            </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane in active fade" id = "main">
            <input type="file" class="fancyfile"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id = "photos">
            <input type="file" class="fancyfile"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id = "contributors">
            <input type="file" class="fancyfile"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('input.fancyfile').fancyfile({
    text: 'Select File',
    icon: '',
    style: 'btn-primary',
    placeholder: 'Select File…'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the exact source of the conflict. Somehow, the width is being set to 11px on the second two tabs. The placeholder text is still there, you just can't see it because of the size of the box.

Here's an easy fix, though: just manually set the width of the input box with css. You have to put the !important flag so the script doesn't override it.

```
.fake-input {
    width: 188px !important; /* same as first one
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bv2swf2t/2/

edit: After reading your comment and looking again, the reason the button doesn't work is that the actual button does nothing. The 'fancyfile' input is supposed to take up the width of the input and the button, which opens up the 'choose file' dialogue. For some reason, the width is getting set to 0px in tabs 2 and 3. Fix is similar to above:

```
.fancyfile {
    width: 280px !important; /* same as first one
}
```

This extends the input box over the button, and matches the functionality of the first box.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, I added `.fancy-file input[type=file] {
    width: 188px !important; 
}` as well to make the clickable area extend across beyond the placeholder. However, clicking the button still submits the form instead of opening the file dialog.

Comment: @schnauss : see answer edit. .fancy-file needs to extend over the button to make it work (width: 280px).